# Order of execution in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

The following query is a contrived example that demonstrates a bug I found in a stored procedure this week.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value char(1)
)

INSERT INTO #temp(Value) Values('a')
INSERT INTO #temp(Value) Values('b')
INSERT INTO #temp(Value) Values('c')
INSERT INTO #temp(Value) Values('d')

DECLARE
    @i int,
    @ID int,
    @Count int,
    @Value char(1)

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM #temp
SET @i = 1
SET @ID = 2

WHILE @i < @Count
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @ID = ID,
        @Value = (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID)
    FROM
        #temp
    WHERE
        @i = ID

    PRINT @Value

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

At first glance the output should be `a b c d` but it isn't! It's `b b c d`. So the order of execution within a statement is not what we might assume it to be.

Is there a specific order of execution that can be relied on?

Comment: Output of your given query is b a b

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I won't change it now because everyone's already commented on it in their answers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WHERE clause in the line

```
@Value = (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID)
```

is uncorrelated with the WHERE clause here

```
    #temp
WHERE
    @i = ID
```

So, 1st loop

- @i = 1, @ID = 2
- In #temp, @ID = 2 so you get `b`
- You then assign @ID with 1

2nd loop

- @i = 2, @ID = 1
- In #temp, @ID = 1 so you get `a`
- You then assign @ID with 2

3rd loop

- @i = 3, @ID = 2
- In #temp, @ID = 2 so you get `b`
- You then assign @ID with 3

Then it stops because of `@i < @count`

SQL has no "order of execution" as such because it's declarative. The SELECT clause is evalauted in one go, there is no expectation that says @ID will be assigned before it uses on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that it prints four letters on your system, `@i < @Count` should limit the output to 3 rows.

You can usually rely on column assignments being evaluated in order.  But a subquery can be evaluated in a different order (or even be converted into a join for efficiency.)  If you separate the assignments from the query using a subquery:

```
SELECT  @ID = ID
,       @Value = TheVal
FROM    (
        SELECT  ID
        ,       (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID) as TheVal
        FROM    #temp
        WHERE   @i = ID
        ) sub
```

The result should be reliable.  Here, it's `b a b` because it starts with `@id = 2`, and then increases it with every loop **after** updating the `TheVal` value.

Relying on this kind of tricks makes for code that is hard to maintain.  It can sometimes be necessary for performance, but if it isn't, try to write for clarity :)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't print four letters. I'm not at the office so I just tapped something out from memory.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL,  all expressions that appear in the same logical query processing phase are evaluated as if at the same point in time.

By this I mean, we cannot say that `@ID= ID` will be evaluated first, and then

```
@Value = (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID).
```

Besides, the order of execution of clauses is :

FROM

WHERE

GROUP BY

HAVING

SELECT

ORDER BY

That's why the aliases of the SELECT clause can only be referenced in the ORDER BY clause.

Cheers.

Comment: So what ? It only inserts data to the table. The issue here is the query inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look closer to your query:

1. The first run:

   SELECT 
           @ID = ID,
           @Value = (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID) 
       FROM
           #temp
       WHERE
           @i = ID

Here

```
 @i=1
   @ID=2
```

so after

```
 @Value = (SELECT Value FROM #temp WHERE ID = @ID)
```

we get:

```
 @Value = 'b'
```

and the @ID value will equal 1 because of @ID=ID, since ID= 1 is the only value available after the

> WHERE
>               @i = ID

is executed.

2. The second run

   @i=2
   @ID=1

This run will print

> 'a'

3
. The third run 
    @id=3
   @ID=2

this run will print

> 'b'

Then the loop terminates !

that's why you got 'b' 'a' 'b'

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as I recently found out, there is a Logical Processing Order (though not a guaranteed physical execution order- as this is based on the query processor)

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

> Logical Processing Order of the SELECT
>   statement
>
> The following steps show the logical
>   processing order, or binding order,
>   for a SELECT statement. This order
>   determines when the objects defined in
>   one step are made available to the
>   clauses in subsequent steps. For
>   example, if the query processor can
>   bind to (access) the tables or views
>   defined in the FROM clause, these
>   objects and their columns are made
>   available to all subsequent steps. 
>   Conversely, because the SELECT clause
>   is step 8, any column aliases or
>   derived columns defined in that clause
>   cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be
>   referenced by subsequent clauses such
>   as the ORDER BY clause. **Note that
>   the actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query
>   processor and the order may vary from
>   this list. (emphasis mine)**
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, and how you get your results.

I pasted your code into MSSQL 2008, and got

> b 
>   a 
>   b

First, you have a "less than Count" comparison, resulting in only 3 records.

Next, you have two contradicting WHERE clauses, one with ID and one with i. The SELECT updates the ID.

Remove the subselect, and change to <= @Count, and you should get "a b c d"